# Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am querying a collection for documents using below code. Document names are same as device names. The device name is passed to the document from an API I am getting an error when a device name contains letter "/" like Motorola C380/C385.
I get an error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference.
>   Document references must have an even number of segments, but
>   Mobiles/Motorola C380/C385 has 3

I know I am getting this error because FireStore considers the name C385 after slash as a collection inside a document. I want to know how to get rid of situations like this when a document name can contain a "/" should I check and remove this before inserting it into my collection or is there any better solution?

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Mobiles").document(response.body().get(finalI).getDeviceName())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
response.body().get(finalI).getDeviceName().toString().replace("/","_")
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method I can think of, is before you add the data to the database to find that forbidden `/` symbol and replace it with an allowed one, let's say `-` (minus).

```
String deviceName = response.body().get(finalI).getDeviceName().replaceAll("/", "-");
```

And then simply use in your reference like this:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Mobiles").document(deviceName);
```

Comment: Hi walter! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

**A possibility can be**

Make sure your document name is not empty in my case it was empty then i also  got the same error:

eg:-

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("CollectionName").document("");
```

The above code will give the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. 
Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1
```