# How to get, set, update and delete data from the cloud firestore in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I tried some code but getting an exception.

The Exception that I'm getting:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but Users has 1`

I searched for it, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53298957/invalid-document-reference-document-references-must-have-an-even-number-of-segm), Document references must have an even number of segments **like: Collection - document - Collection - document - Collection - document**

**Query for getting data from firestore:**

```
String getIsNewUSer;
Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document(uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot document){
       print("document_build:$document");
        setState(() {
         getIsNewUSer=document['IsNewUser'];
         print("getIsNewUSe:$getIsNewUSer");
        });
             
    });
```

**Query for Updating data to the firestore:**

```
Firestore.instance
            .collection('Users')
            .document(uid)
            .updateData({
              "IsNewUser":"1"
            }).then((result){
              print("new USer true");
            }).catchError((onError){
             print("onError");
            });
```

These code line at I'm getting above Exception.

**initState:**

```
 void initState()  {
    super.initState();
    this.uid = '';

FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((val){
      setState(() {
      this.uid= val.uid; 
       print("uid_init: $uid");
      });
   });

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace this part in your queries:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document(uid)
```

with

```
Firestore.instance.document('Users/$uid')
```

> Collection - document - Collection - document - Collection - document

Basically you already had the answer.

Comment: Hello @Shruti Ramnandan Sharma!
If this answer worked out for you, would you mind accepting it? That way tt will have more visibility on the community and other users with the same doubt may benefit from it!

Answer (score 16):

#### Null safe code:

- **Get data:**

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
  var docSnapshot = await collection.doc('doc_id').get();
  Map<String, dynamic>? data = docSnapshot.data();
  ```
- **Set data:**

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
  collection.add(someData);
  ```
- **Update data**:

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
  collection 
      .doc('foo_id') // <-- Doc ID where data should be updated.
      .update(newData);
  ```
- **Delete data:**

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
  collection 
      .doc('some_id') // <-- Doc ID to be deleted. 
      .delete();
  ```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` future didn't complete and populte `this.uid`. So `this.uid` == '' (empty string). So Firestore is throwing errror as you are trying to updated document at `Users` which is a collection.

You can validate this by printing `this.uid` before the update statement.

One way is to use helper method to update

```
Future<void> update(Map data) async {
    final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    return Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document(user.uid).updateData(data);
}
```

Then you can use helpr method as `update({isNewUser: "1"}).then((r) {...})....`

You can follow same approach for fetching the document as well.

Comment: I think it would, Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document(uid) should be replacable to Firestore.instance.document('Users/$uid'). I guess the main issue here is uid is not set (so default value '') by the time query is fired.

Comment: Have you ever tried it? It doen't work that way. Even if it is logically correct, but firestore requires you to write the document path with even number of parts.

Comment: I use this pattern heavily. e.g. https://github.com/yagnyam-in/proxy-flutter/blob/master/lib/db/firestore_utils.dart. This app is on playstore and appstore.

Comment: you can not use "then" after "update". It returns void