# 'Document references must have an even number of segments' in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Where i am going wrong it shows error whenever i try to read data from my firestore.[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1, null)
The code is :

```
bool hasData = false;
  String number;
  var val;
  final usersRef = Firestore.instance.collection('users');

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.number = '';
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        val = value;
        this.number = value.phoneNumber;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
    checkData();
    super.initState();
  }

  checkData() async {
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.document(this.number).get();
    if (doc.exists) {
      setState(() {
        hasData = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        hasData = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

The error is:

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.forPath(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:80)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.document(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:249)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.getDocumentReference(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:115)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.onMethodCall(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:890)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:226)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:631)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore( 4166):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/flutter ( 4166): **[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1, null)**
E/flutter ( 4166): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
E/flutter ( 4166): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18)
E/flutter ( 4166): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4166): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
E/flutter ( 4166): #3      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:356:48)
E/flutter ( 4166): #4      MethodChannelDocumentReference.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:56:46)
E/flutter ( 4166): #5      DocumentReference.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:69:47)
E/flutter ( 4166): #6      _CreateUserState.checkData (package:knowledgehub/createuser.dart:36:65)
E/flutter ( 4166): #7      _CreateUserState.initState (package:knowledgehub/createuser.dart:31:5)
E/flutter ( 4166): #8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4640:58)
E/flutter ( 4166): #9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter ( 4166): #10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 4166): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3211:20)
E/flutter ( 4166): #12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter ( 4166): #13     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
E/flutter ( 4166): #14     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter ( 4166): #15     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2627:33)
E/flutter ( 4166): #16     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:20)
E/flutter ( 4166): #17     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:284:5)
E/flutter ( 4166): #18     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:15)
E/flutter ( 4166): #19     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1052:9)
E/flutter ( 4166): #20     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:968:5)
E/flutter ( 4166): #21     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter ( 4166): #22     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter ( 4166): #23     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter ( 4166): #24     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:261:10)
E/flutter ( 4166): #25     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:3)
E/flutter ( 4166): 
I/flutter ( 4166): +91xxxxxxxxxx
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4166): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4166): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4166): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4166): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4166): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 4166): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
I/flutter ( 4166): Suraj Jha
W/co.knowledgehu( 4166): Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
W/co.knowledgehu( 4166): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (light greylist, reflection)
W/co.knowledgehu( 4166): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, linking)
W/co.knowledgehu( 4166): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, linking)
W/co.knowledgehu( 4166): Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (light greylist, JNI)
W/co.knowledgehu( 4166): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
W/co.knowledgehu( 4166): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (light greylist, linking)
W/co.knowledgehu( 4166): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (light greylist, linking)
I/flutter ( 4166): Instance of 'User'
W/co.knowledgehu( 4166): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (light greylist, linking)
W/co.knowledgehu( 4166): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, linking)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set, get and update data to the cloud firestore in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58077155/how-to-set-get-and-update-data-to-the-cloud-firestore-in-flutter)

Comment: That answer didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable number doesn't have any valid value, it's just an empty `String`.Since you are using `.then` the `checkData()` function will be called directly without waiting for the number to be assigned. Instead of using `.then` you can use `await`

```
var result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
number = result.phoneNumber;
checkData();
```

I hope this helps.