# What page users currently opening/seeing (Flutter/Firebase)

Tags: firebase, flutter

Is there any possibility to retrieve the information, which page in the app are the users currently on using flutter and firebase? I'm currently implementing a live group chat function and want to show which users are actively (online) participating in which group.

So far I've implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58077155/how-to-get-set-update-and-delete-data-from-the-cloud-firestore-in-flutter) to know whether some users online or not but I would like to further know where they are during that time.

Comment: I was thinking probably a combination between the information of whether user are  online or not + the last page user accessed would be an alternative. But I would like to know if there are any other/ possibly better solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I just have an idea where when a user enters to a group you can save the group id in the firebase and show user online status as per the id, and when the user exit from the group you can remove the id from the firebase (use will pop scope widget to detect exiting from a screen)
hope this helps